# How to use Wikipedia API to edit a page on browser javascript?

Tags: javascript, wikipedia, wikipedia-api

The script is intended to be injected into  the Wikipedia site. It will use the users' login credentials to post to the edit API.

This is my attempt:

```
function getEditToken(){
    return fetch(
        'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&meta=tokens&format=json',
        {credentials: 'include'}
    )
    .then( r => r.json() )
    .then( r => r.query.tokens.csrftoken )
}

function writeRevision(title, text, summary){
    var url = `https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?action=edit`
    var formData = new FormData()
    formData.append('title', title)
    formData.append('text', text)
    formData.append('summary', summary)    
    formData.append('contentmodel', 'wikitext') 

    var option = {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData,
        credentials: 'include',
    }

    return getEditToken()
    .then( token => { formData.append('token', token); console.log(token) } )
    .then( x => fetch(url, option) )
    .then( r => r.text() )
    .then( console.log )
    .catch( e => console.log(e) )

}

writeRevision('User:eeeeeeeee/draft_1', 'foo wikitext', 'foo summary')
```

The response says:

> Some parts of the edit form did not reach the server; double-check
>   that your edits are intact and try again.

Comment: Do you include any hidden field which are usually sent when editing wikipedia pages? Compare what chrome logs into the "network" tab when using your script and regular wikipedia, are the same field sent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [the MediaWiki edit API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Edit) to edit pages. Don't post to `?action=edit` directly; that URI is for interactive clients.

The MediaWiki API documentation includes an example of how to do this with Javascript, which I've reproduced below:

```
function addNewSection( summary, content, editToken ) {
    $.ajax({
        url: mw.util.wikiScript( 'api' ),
        data: {
            format: 'json',
            action: 'edit',
            title: mw.config.get( 'wgPageName' ),
            section: 'new',
            summary: summary,
            text: content,
            token: editToken
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function( data ) {
            if ( data && data.edit && data.edit.result == 'Success' ) {
                window.location.reload(); // reload page if edit was successful
            } else if ( data && data.error ) {
                alert( 'Error: API returned error code "' + data.error.code + '": ' + data.error.info );
            } else {
                alert( 'Error: Unknown result from API.' );
            }
        },
        error: function( xhr ) {
            alert( 'Error: Request failed.' );
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Many thanks... Another another day spent on a typo. I dig in lines and lines of source code and didn't find this.

Answer (score 4):

If the code is running in the browser (and thus has access to MediaWiki's javascript modules), you can just use [`mw.Api.edit`](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/source/mediawiki/browse/master/resources/src/mediawiki/api/edit.js;4b7be839091cdc0b4a942532456633fa5b5f3429$63):

```
function edit( title, text, summary ) {
    mw.loader.using( 'mediawiki.api.edit' ).then( function () {
        let api = new mw.Api();
        api.edit( title, function () {
            return {
                text: text,
                summary: summary
            };
        } );
    } );
}
```